# How can I collect ids from a list of JSON objects into a list?

Tags: json, jq

I want to do some filter with jq command. My input json body is as of such format:

```
    {
      "payload": {
        "count": 23,
        "results": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bob"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name" "John"
          }
       ]
     }
   }
```

And I want to get the results as such:

```
{"count": 23, "users": [2, 5]}
```

where all the ids are grouped into an array. How the jq command would look like ?

Thanks.

Chun

Comment: Did you try something? lookup similar questions?

Comment: I could not find the answer myself. Do you know where to look at ?

Comment: This could really use a better title. How is anyone else with the same problem, looking at "how to get such results by jq command" in search results, supposed to know if the question and its answers will help them?

Comment: ...one example of a more specific question title might be: *How can I collect ids from a list of JSON objects into a list with only those ids?* -- assuming that that is in fact where you got stuck. (Part of why we ask you to show your work is to make it clear what you do already understand, to allow a better focus on just where the problem is).

Comment: Thanks. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and have tried some different options, I have just figured out how to make it work, which is:

```sh
echo "$json" | jq -c '{"count": .payload.count, "users": [.payload.results[].id]}'
```

Comment: Or more DRYly: `jq -c '.payload | {count, "users": [.results[].id]}'`